# CSS Issue with Contact Form

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the CSS for a contact form. I've removed my CSS so it's clean without the mess.

I want the input fields to be full width and in blocks. I also want the first and last name at 50% of the full width next to each other on the same line.

Support would be much appreciated!

```css
div.name,
div.email,
div.organisation,
div.phone-number,
div.hear,
div.enquiry,
div.footer {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" size="1000" value="" name="FNAME" class="first-name" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="601" />
  <br>

  <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="602" />
  <br>
</div>

<div class='email'>
  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="603" />
  <br>
</div>

<div class='organisation'>
  <input type="text" value="" name="ORGANISATI" class="organisation" placeholder="What organisation are you representing?" tabindex="604" />
  <br>
</div>

<div class='phone-number'>
  <input type="text" value="" name="NUMBER" class="number" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="605" />
  <br>
</div>

<div class="hear">
  <select name="HEAR" class="required" id="mce-HEAR">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="enquiry">
  <textarea name="ENQUIRY" cols="60" rows="10" class="required" placeholder="What is your enquiry?" tabindex="607" />
  <br>
</div>
<br>

<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->

<div class="footer">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="subscribe" class="submit om-trigger-conversion" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `textarea` is not an autoclosed balise..

Comment: Would you mind using one of the existing CSS frameworks like Bootstrap? This will make your life easy.

Comment: <textarea></textarea> - close your textarea like this

Answer (score 2):

I think if you take out the `<br>` between the first name and last name inputs, you will get them on the same line.

http://jsbin.com/bitaha/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You must close `textarea` tag, please update this code:

```
<div class="enquiry">
  <textarea name="ENQUIRY" cols="60" rows="10" class="required" placeholder="What is your enquiry?" tabindex="607" />
 <br>
```

to:

```
<div class="enquiry">
  <textarea name="ENQUIRY" cols="60" rows="10" class="required" placeholder="What is your enquiry?" tabindex="607" /></textarea>
 <br>
```

Simple style for this form: [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/ZWgage)

Comment: Great, thanks!

Any ideas about the necessary css for the rest of the contact form please?

Comment: I added simple style form link in my answer. Hope it help you and please up vote and accept my answer if it helpful with you :) Looking your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the break, `<br />`, between the first and last name. Then set the width to 50% like this:

`.firstname, .lastname  {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}.`

or

`input[name=FNAME], input[name=LNAME] {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}`

**NOTE** : I'm not sure of the code because I used a not-much-reliable debugger i.e my eyes

Answer (score 0):

It's not necesarry to use div in your css selectors, I've used some classes similar to bootstrap's form inputs. I recommend you learning to use a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) it will help you in this sort of things and many more.

```css
textarea {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.form-group {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.form-control {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}
.form-control.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="name" id="name">
      <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="first-name form-control inline" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="601" />

      <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="last-name form-control inline" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="602" />
    </div>

    <div class="email">
      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email form-control" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="603" />
    </div>

    <div class='organisation'>
      <input type="text" value="" name="ORGANISATI" class="organisation form-control" placeholder="What organisation are you representing?" tabindex="604" />
    </div>

    <div class='phone-number'>
      <input type="text" value="" name="NUMBER" class="number form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="605" />
    </div>

    <div class="hear">
      <select name="HEAR" class="required form-control" id="mce-HEAR">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="enquiry">
      <textarea name="ENQUIRY" cols="60" rows="10" class="required form-control" placeholder="What is your enquiry?" tabindex="607"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->

    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" value="Send" name="subscribe" class="submit om-trigger-conversion btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```